# How Do I Import a Non-Android Eclipse Maven Project into Android Studio?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am starting at a disadvantage as I know neither Eclipse, Gradle or Android Studio.  As such, I may not be using the correct terminology for everything, but I'll give it a shot.  My ultimate goal is to get a working Eclipse-based Android app imported into Android Studio and hand it back to the Android developer.  This question is about a problem I encountered on the way.

I have successfully imported the main Android project into AS.  Now I'm trying to pull in another project it depends upon as a module.  The dependency is a Maven project.  It has a pom.xml, a .project and a .classpath.  It's not an Android project, so there's no AndroidManifest.xml.  It has a src but no res folder.  I want this project to be a module rather than an external dependency as the developer will modify the source code on occasion.

The problem is that AS refuses to accept the project as an importable module.  The Add Module dialog, when pointed to the project's root directory, continues to warn that I haven't yet selected a valid Android Eclipse or Gradle project.  The Next button stays grayed-out.  I agree that this is neither an Android-specific nor a Gradle project, but I have read [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Import+an+Existing+Project) that IntelliJ IDEA will import such projects.  It appears that AS will not.

There are several other non-Android Eclipse projects that also won't import as modules in the same way.  These include ordinary Maven and ant-based libraries.

How do I accomplish this?  The GUI seems out to thwart me.  If I get down to the Gradle XML level, can I do it and will the modules show up normally in the GUI?  Do I have to go back to Eclipse and convert these to Gradle projects first?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have to use Android Studio and not IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition? Unlike Android Studio, IntelliJ IDEA has full support for Maven projects.

Comment: In general, module import should work, but without more details about how the module is structured I can't say why it isn't working in your case. Android Studio doesn't support projects with mixed build systems, so it will have to be all the same thing, preferably Gradle. Yes, you can set up Gradle build files by hand for modules you want to bring in, but if you can get import working the IDE will do it for you. Build files are executable programs in Groovy, btw, not simple XML files.

Comment: @yole - As I [read more](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/), that is looking like an attractive solution.  However, my challenge will be selling something other than Google's recommended IDE to management.  There is already divergence between the two solutions that may increase in the future.

Comment: @yole - I am test driving IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.  I imported the main Android Eclipse project and then imported, as a module, the Maven Eclipse project xxx that I was unable to import in Android Studio.  I did this by pointing the Import Module dialog at the pom.xml file.  So far so good.  However, when I try to build the project, I get: "Error:Unable to make the module: xxx, related gradle configuration was not found. Please, re-import the Gradle project and try again."  Of course xxx was never a Gradle project, and I would expect IDEA to build it with Maven.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am confused by the differences between how AS imports Eclipse projects versus how IDEA does it.  When I used AS, it automatically generated the Gradle files for me but refused to import the Maven project.  When I used IDEA, it happily imported both Eclipse projects but it Gradled neither.  Yet when IDEA is told to build the Maven project, it complains that there are no Gradle files.  So am I expected to manually provide the Gradle stuff for IDEA, or is there a GUI button in IDEA or Eclipse that will do that for me?  I'd appreciate any guidance here.